# Extract image src from <img>tag android

Tags: android, html, regex

I have some `img` tags in html. I used Regex to get `img` tags. I wrote some code and my code is working on only one `img` tag.

```
String imgRegex = "<[iI][mM][gG][^>]+[sS][rR][cC]\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(imgRegex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);

        if (m.find()) {
            String imgSrc = m.group(1);

            String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/tanadgomaaa";
            String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
            imgSrc=imgSrc.replace(imgSrc,imagePath);



        }
```

Can enyone tell me how I can get all `img` tags from html string?
thanks

Comment: Example of a string you are trying to get it from would be helpful

Comment: @engineer14 can you tell me how i can solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language (`java`?) you are using but I'd imagine there is a case insensitive modifier you could use for the regex rather than character classing each version of a character. There probably is a parser that would also be able to pull all images pretty easily.

Comment: it's harder if we don't have an example, but here is a try

use a while loop instead of the if statement, ie while (m.find())

Comment: You might find it nice to hear that you can do incase sensitive matches: `(?i)<img...`

Comment: and btw, for java, if you use (?i) which is the case insensitive modifier, you can replace all the single upper/lower character matches you have with:

(?i)<img[^>]+?src\\s*=\\s*...

Comment: am i missing something here, why are you using group(1)?

Comment: Oh, for some reason i was thinking you wanted the whole string (ie group(0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String imgRegex = "(?i)<img[^>]+?src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(imgRegex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);

    while(m.find()) {
        String imgSrc = m.group(1);

        String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/tanadgomaaa";
        String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
        imgSrc=imgSrc.replace(imgSrc,imagePath);



    }
```